# displaying results together by username

Tags: php, pdo

im trying to print out 1 result for each users orders so each item the user orders is saved has its own row so i would like to group them all together and print them out but my coding prints them out 1 by 1

which displays this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujcX0.png)

Has you can see it outputs them item by item but i would like to output everything shadow has ordered inside 1 box then the next user in the other box etc

My table info is here
http://prntscr.com/fxv2fr

there are 2 boxes right?? For the same users? different results /item name but the same user i need to group the select by users so it posts everything each user wants into 1 box instead of having 100 boxes for 100 items for 1 user so if users 1 wants 2 different items and user 2 wants 3 different items instead of having 5 boxes there would be 2 due to 2 users in the table with 2 items in the first box for user1 and 3 in the second box for user 2 and it would keep doing this for all

```
                         <?php

                          $id2 = "1";                     
                         $paid = "1";
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM orders WHERE takeawayid=:restaurantid AND paid =:paid ORDER BY id ');
 $query->execute(array(':restaurantid' => $id2,':paid' => $paid));

    // alternatively you could use PDOStatement::fetchAll() and get rid of the loop
    // this is dependent upon the design of your app


    while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {



    $query2 = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE takeawayid=:restaurantid AND paid =:paid AND forwho=:forwho ORDER BY id");
 $query2->execute(array(':restaurantid' => $id2,':paid' => $paid,':forwho' => $row['forwho']));


        while ($d = $query2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))



 {









    ?>


                     <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="widget">
                           <div class="widget-body">


                       <!-- end: ddsdsd -->        







<div class="row">
<div class="restaurant-listing">







                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 single-restaurant grill fish thaifood pizza">
                            <div class="restaurant-wrap">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-12 col-lg-3 text-xs-center">
                                        <a class="" href="#"> <img src="http://santetotal.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/default-user.png" alt="Restaurant logo" height="92" width="102"> </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <!--end:col -->
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-12 col-lg-9">
                                        <h5><a href="profile.html"><?php echo $d['itemname'] ;?></a></h5> <span></span>
                                        <div class="bottom-part">

                                            <div class="ratings"> <span>








                                                </span>  </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- end:col -->
                                </div>
                                <!-- end:row -->
                            </div>
                            <!--end:Restaurant wrap -->
                        </div>
                        <!--end: col -->



                    </div>
                </div>
       <!-- end: ddsdsd -->   

        <?php echo $d['forwho'] ;  $price.=$d['price'];?>      







                           </div>
                           <!-- end: Widget -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- /REGISTER -->
                     </div>
                     <!-- WHY? -->


        <?php


    }
    echo "Total: ".$price."</div>";
}

                        ?>
```

my above code doesnt group the users so what i need is for each user inside forwho column has 1 box each with all there results in instead its making 1 box for each results

Comment: I see you have the column `forwho` in orders. Actually is bad design, because `forwho` is textual. There should be the `user_id` column instead. So, in `users` table each user should have an user id. And exactly this user id should be placed instead of current `forwho`. Question: Do you have the possibility to change 'forwho' to a `user_id` column containing user ids instead of names?

Comment: Which database are you using? MySQL?

Comment: yes i can change the forwho there is also a id column in the users table and yes mysql database im trying to make a online food order website were users can order food ive coded the menu and ordering part now just need to display the orders for the take aways to view so i need somthing were it displays all orders for each user in 1 box per a user so username 1 has ordered chips etc   then username2 has ordered xyz but instead its doing username1 ordered chips username 1 ordered xyz   and so on

Comment: above code works http://prntscr.com/fy94ec  but has u can see displays wrongly

Comment: Ok, so: box 1 for user 1 with items 1, 2 and 3, followed by box 2 for user 2 with products 2, 8 and 12, and so on ?

Comment: No you got the box / username correct  i have a table called "topics"  i know its wrong to name it that but its a  item list http://prntscr.com/fy9aob so the take aways menu is stored in here they store each item in here each and every take away store the topic_by is the takeaways username then when the user buys a item it gets placed in the orders table  http://prntscr.com/fy9bbf  i dont know what you mean by 2, 8 and 12 ?? but user1 has a box for all the orders they have placed then user2 has all the orders they have placed all there results from order table

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I meant: box 1 for user 1 with ORDERS 1, 2 and 3, followed by box 2 for user 2 with ORDERS 2, 8 and 12, and so on. I wanted to mean "orders" but, silly me, I used "item" and "products" :-)

Comment: yes so ALL orders any users place get stored  in the order table its grabs the price  and item id etc from the topic table then insert it into the order table ive done that and works great but now i need to display the orders to the take aways so i can say user1 wants x y and z from you user2 wants x y z from you instead its printing otu user1 want x user1 also wants y user 1 wants z  when it should be user1 wants x  y z in 1 order box  but instead its display every item in each box https://prnt.sc/fy94ec when each USER should be in a different box

Comment: ok, I understand. I'll develop it.

Comment: ok thank you if u need any more tables let me know

Comment: guess you cant do it??

Comment: You wanna bet? :-)

Comment: well its been a hour?? maybe 2 ?

Comment: Well, my friend, welcome to the real programming world! You want a great solution or just a patch?

Comment: ill wait :) good luck with it :) you wont need it

Comment: I admire your patience :-))

Comment: 3 hours ago :( ...

Comment: Right now I post it.

Comment: fixed it all ready i believe

Comment: http://prntscr.com/fyb06r had ago but still broekn

Comment: Shadow, first of all: I had a system out because of battery down :-) Now, it taked somehow a long time because I wanted to give you a professional solution, so that you see how the whole cycle of db connecting, db fetching, error reporting and exception handling should look like. I hope you'll understand all. If not, feel free to ask me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give it a try.

- You should create only one PDO instance, e.g. connection. It should be passed as argument to each function that uses it.
- Of course, transfer `style` attributes to classes. I implemented my own html.

**Some recommendations:**

- Try to move to OOP.
- Apply exception handling and activate error reporting/handling. I gave you a general view by throwing only `Exception`. Normally you should throw and handle the [SPL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php) (Standard PHP Library) subtypes of it.
- Always read in the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/) what PHP functions are returning so that you can correctly apply handle cases (exceptions, bools, etc).

Resources:

- [The Clean Code Talks - Don't Look For Things!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0)
- [Dependency Injection and Dependency Inversion in PHP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ojsn11XY0X8&feature=youtu.be)
- [Exception handling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)
- [Predefined Exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.exceptions.php)
- [SPL Exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/spl.exceptions.php)
- [Errors and error handling](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php)

---

Here is the code, spread (as it should) on four PHP pages. `index.php` is the main page, the others are included in it.

#### index.php

```
<?php
require_once 'configs.php';
require_once 'generalFunctions.php';
require_once 'ordersFunctions.php';

// Activate error reporting (only on development).
activateErrorReporting();

try {
    // Create db connection.
    $connection = createConnection(
            MYSQL_HOST
            , MYSQL_DATABASE
            , MYSQL_USERNAME
            , MYSQL_PASSWORD
            , MYSQL_PORT
            , MYSQL_CHARSET
    );

    $takeawayId = 1;
    $paid = 1;

    // Fetch paid orders by takeaway.
    $fetchedOrders = fetchPaidOrdersByTakeaway($connection, $takeawayId, $paid);

    // For testing.
    // printData($fetchedOrders, TRUE);
    // Close connection
    closeConnection($connection);
} catch (PDOException $pdoException) {
    // On development.
    printData($pdoException, TRUE);

    // On production.
    // echo $pdoException->getMessage();
    exit();
} catch (Exception $exception) {
    // On development.
    printData($exception, TRUE);

    // On production.
    // echo $exception->getMessage();
    exit();
}

// Group orders by users.
$ordersByUsers = groupOrdersByUsers($fetchedOrders);

// For testing.
// printData($ordersByUsers, TRUE);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Orders</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container" style="margin-top: 40px;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <?php
                    foreach ($ordersByUsers as $userId => $item) {
                        $username = $item['username'];
                        $ordersPrice = $item['ordersPrice'];
                        $orders = $item['orders'];
                        ?>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-10" style="background-color: #FAFAF8; border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
                                <div class="row" style="padding: 20px;">
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <a href="#">
                                                <img src="http://santetotal.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/default-user.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Restaurant logo" height="92" width="102">
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row" style="padding-top: 10px;">
                                            <a href="#" style="text-transform: uppercase;">
                                                <?php echo $username; ?>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
                                        <?php
                                        foreach ($orders as $order) {
                                            $orderId = $order['orderId'];
                                            $itemname = $order['itemname'];
                                            $price = $order['price'];
                                            $date = $order['date'];
                                            ?>
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-xs-12" style="background-color: #FFF; border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
                                                    <h4>
                                                        <a href="profile.html" style="color: orange;">
                                                            <?php echo $itemname; ?>
                                                        </a>
                                                    </h4>
                                                    <div>
                                                        <div>
                                                            <span>
                                                                <?php echo $date; ?>
                                                            </span>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="ratings">
                                                            <span>5 STARS</span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <?php
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2" style="padding: 20px; padding-top: 40px; font-size: 20px; color: #666; text-transform: uppercase;">
                                Total: <?php echo $ordersPrice; ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

#### orderFunctions.php

```
<?php

/*
 * ---------------------
 * Orders functions
 * ---------------------
 */

/**
 * Fetch paid orders by takeaway.
 * 
 * @param PDO $connection Connection instance.
 * @param integer $takeawayId Takeaway ID.
 * @param integer $paid Paid.
 * @throws Exception
 */
function fetchPaidOrdersByTakeaway($connection, $takeawayId, $paid) {
    if (!isset($takeawayId)) {
        throw new Exception('Takeaway ID not provided!');
    }

    if (!isset($paid)) {
        throw new Exception('Paid not provided!');
    }

    // Sql statement.
    $sql = 'SELECT 
                ord.id AS orderId,
                usr.id AS userId,
                usr.username,
                ord.itemname,
                ord.price,
                ord.date
            FROM orders AS ord 
            LEFT JOIN users AS usr ON usr.id = ord.user_id 
            WHERE 
                takeawayid = :takeawayid 
                AND paid = :paid 
            ORDER BY 
                usr.username ASC,
                ord.date DESC';

    // Prepare and check sql statement (returns PDO statement).
    $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
    if (!$statement) {
        throw new Exception('The SQL statement can not be prepared!');
    }

    // Bind values to sql statement parameters.
    $statement->bindValue(':takeawayid', $takeawayId, getInputParameterDataType($takeawayId));
    $statement->bindValue(':paid', $paid, getInputParameterDataType($paid));

    // Execute and check PDO statement.
    if (!$statement->execute()) {
        throw new Exception('The PDO statement can not be executed!');
    }

    // Fetch data.
    $fetchedData = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if ($fetchedData === FALSE) {
        throw new Exception('Fetching data failed!');
    }

    return $fetchedData;
}

/**
 * Group orders by users.
 * 
 * @param array $orders [optional] Orders list.
 * @return array Orders list grouped by users.
 * @throws Exception
 */
function groupOrdersByUsers(array $orders = array()) {
    $groupedOrders = array();

    foreach ($orders as $order) {
        $userId = $order['userId'];
        $username = $order['username'];
        $price = $order['price'];

        // Check and add user name as key, if not already.
        if (!array_key_exists($userId, $groupedOrders)) {
            $groupedOrders[$userId] = array(
                'username' => $username,
                'orders' => array(),
                'ordersPrice' => 0,
            );
        }

        // Add order to grouped orders list.
        $groupedOrders[$userId]['orders'][] = $order;
        $groupedOrders[$userId]['ordersPrice'] += $price;
    }

    return $groupedOrders;
}
```

#### configs.php

```
<?php

/*
 * ----------------
 * Database configs
 * ----------------
 */

define('MYSQL_HOST', '...');
define('MYSQL_PORT', '3306');
define('MYSQL_DATABASE', '...');
define('MYSQL_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('MYSQL_USERNAME', '...');
define('MYSQL_PASSWORD', '...');
```

#### generalFunctions.php

```
<?php

/*
 * ---------------------
 * Data access functions
 * ---------------------
 */

/**
 * Create a new db connection.
 * 
 * @param string $host Host.
 * @param string $dbname Database name.
 * @param string $username Username.
 * @param string $password Password.
 * @param string $port [optional] Port.
 * @param array $charset [optional] Character set.
 * @param array $options [optional] Driver options.
 * @return PDO Db connection.
 */
function createConnection($host, $dbname, $username, $password, $port = '3306', $charset = 'utf8', $options = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
)) {
    $dsn = getDsn($host, $dbname, $port, $charset);
    $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
    foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
        $connection->setAttribute($key, $value);
    }
    return $connection;
}

/**
 * Create a mysql DSN string.
 * 
 * @param string $host Host.
 * @param string $dbname Database name.
 * @param string $port [optional] Port.
 * @param array $charset [optional] Character set.
 * @return string DSN string.
 */
function getDsn($host, $dbname, $port = '3306', $charset = 'utf8') {
    $dsn = sprintf('mysql:host=%s;port=%s;dbname=%s;charset=%s'
            , $host
            , $port
            , $dbname
            , $charset
    );
    return $dsn;
}

/**
 * Close a db connection.
 * 
 * @param PDO $connection Db connection.
 * @return void
 */
function closeConnection($connection) {
    $connection = NULL;
}

/**
 * Get the data type of a binding value.
 * 
 * @param mixed $value Binding value.
 * @return mixed Data type of the binding value.
 */
function getInputParameterDataType($value) {
    $dataType = PDO::PARAM_STR;
    if (is_int($value)) {
        $dataType = PDO::PARAM_INT;
    } elseif (is_bool($value)) {
        $dataType = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
    }
    return $dataType;
}

/*
 * ---------------
 * Print functions
 * ---------------
 */

/**
 * Print data on screen.
 * 
 * @param mixed $data Data to print.
 * @param bool $preformatted Print preformatted if TRUE, print normal otherwise.
 * @return void
 */
function printData($data, $preformatted = FALSE) {
    if ($preformatted) {
        echo '<pre>' . print_r($data, true) . '</pre>';
    } else {
        echo $data;
    }
}

/*
 * -------------------------
 * Error reporting functions
 * -------------------------
 */

/**
 * Toggle error reporting.
 * 
 * @param integer $level Error level.
 * @param bool $displayErrors Display errors if TRUE, hide them otherwise.
 * @return void
 */
function activateErrorReporting($level = E_ALL, $displayErrors = TRUE) {
    error_reporting($level);
    ini_set('display_errors', ($displayErrors ? 1 : 0));
}
```

### Used tables:

#### `users` table

[image: users table]

#### `items` table

[image: items table]

#### `orders` table

[image: users table]

### Result:

[image]

Comment: i get a white blank page with this

Comment: No way :-) Step by step then: have you completed your own db credentials?

Comment: One second please

Comment: got a problem http://prntscr.com/fyb77x  the user id is not user_id  its just id were do i change this ??

Comment: Ok, so that you know, I reedited my answer and put the tables I used and the html result. Now we can make it really work.

Comment: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'ord.user_id' in 'on clause'
    [string:Exception:private] =>    [previous:Exception:private] => 
    [errorInfo] => Array
        (
            [0] => 42S22
            [1] => 1054
            [2] => Unknown column 'ord.user_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: Give me: the name of your users table and the column names in it.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/fyb8oy  <-- user table  http://prntscr.com/fyb8uu <-- order table http://prntscr.com/fyb923 <-- my item table which needs to be changed to match yours ?

Comment: willing to rename what ever i need to rename

Comment: Yes, so the probkem is: in table `users` you have id, username and name. So, in table `orders`, in the column `user_id`, you have to write the values from `id` from table `users`. In `orders.user_id` should be integers, not texts.

Comment: would it be easyier to rename id to user_id in the user table??

Comment: there is all ready a id collum inside the orders table for the order id

Comment: Shadow, follow my steps, please: 1) give me a photo with 5 records from `users` table. I wait.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/fybcun i can see why it took you so long now so much effort put into it do u have skype or a email? Maybe if i get stuck again i could offer a paid work?

Comment: yes in side the order table i was storing the username and not the user id so i simple changed the value from there username to there id and worked

Comment: Exactly. That were the problem ;-)

Comment: just hope i bump into you again if i ever have any more problems :) Thank you

Comment: Ok, already done. So good luck and feel free to ask us here or email me. I help you with pleasure if I have time. Bye.

Comment: again thank you so much been trying to fix it for about a week now so thank you so much.

Comment: You are very welcome. Again, I appreciated your patience! :-)))) Ciao